# Solve a system of non-linear equations

Tags: equation-solving

Is there any way to get an exact solution a system of non-linear equations?

The system I would like to solve is:

$\quad \quad 
\begin{eqnarray}
h_{1}x_{1}=c_{1}\\
h_{2}x_{2}=c_{2}\\
h_{3}(1-x_{1}-x_{2})=c_{3}\\
h_{1}h_{2}y_{12}=c_{12}\\
-h_{1}h_{3}y_{11}-h_{1}h_{3}y_{12}=c_{13}\\
-h_{2}h_{3}y_{22}-h_{2}h_{3}y_{12}=c_{23}\\
h_{1}^2y_{11}+y_{0}=c_{11}\\
h_{2}^2y_{22}+y_{0}=c_{22}\\
h_{3}^2(y_{11}+y_{22}+2y_{12})+y_{0}=c_{33}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$

where $h_{1},h_{2},h_{3},x_{1},x_{2},y_{12},y_{11},y_{22},y_{0}$ are unknowns, and $c_{1},c_{2},c_{3}.c_{13},c_{23},c_{11},c_{22},c_{33}$ are known constants.

How can I get an  exact solution in terms of 
$h_{1},\,h_{2},\,h_{3},\,x_{1},\,x_{2},\,y_{12},\,y_{11},\,y_{22},\,y_{0}$

I tried the following *Mathematica* code, but it's been running for long time without any results. Can anyone help?

```
Solve[
  h1*w1 == c1 &&
  h2*w2 == c2 &&
  h3*(1 - w1 - w2) == c3 &&
  h1*h2*y12 == c12 &&
  -h1*h3*y11 - h1*h3*y12 == c13 &&
  -h2*h3*y22 - h2*h3*y12 == c23 &&
  h1^2*y11 + y0 == c11 &&
  h2^2*y22 + y0 == c22 &&
  h3^2*(y11 + y22 + 2*y12) + y0 == c33, 
  {h1, w1, h2, w2, h3, y12, y11, y22, y0}]
```

Comment: …and you've tried using `Solve[]`?

Comment: Why not try it yourself first and report back?

Comment: Being a member for almost 60 days I can't help it, but wonder -- Haven't you noticed the formatted code, $\LaTeX$ typeset formulas, etc ? Aren't you trying to improve the readability of your posts ?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: the equations are algebraic, tho; one wonders if there is at least expressions in terms of `Root[]`…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. You are correct.  The nine equations almost certainly can be combined into one polynomial equation of order nine or higher.  Perhaps, `Solve` needs some help, perhaps by systematically eliminating variables a few at a time with `Eliminate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some progress can  be made using `Eliminate`.

```
Eliminate[
   h1*w1 == c1 &&
   h2*w2 == c2 &&
   h3*(1 - w1 - w2) == c3 &&
   h1*h2*y12 == c12 &&
   -h1*h3*y11 - h1*h3*y12 == c13 &&
   -h2*h3*y22 - h2*h3*y12 == c23 &&
   h1^2*y11 + y0 == c11 &&
   h2^2*y22 + y0 == c22 &&
   h3^2*(y11 + y22 + 2*y12) + y0 == c33,
   {w1, w2, y0}] // Simplify

{* c11 + h3^2 (y11 + 2 y12 + y22) == c33 + h1^2 y11 && 
   c12 == h1 h2 y12 &&
   c13 + h1 h3 (y11 + y12) == 0 && 
   c22 + h3^2 (y11 + 2 y12 + y22) == c33 + h2^2 y22 && 
   c23 + h2 h3 (y12 + y22) == 0 && 
   c3 h1 h2 + c2 h1 h3 + c1 h2 h3 == h1 h2 h3 *)
```

Attempting `Eliminate[%, {y12, y22, y11}]` did not return an answer in a reasonable amount of time, so I begin  eliminating variables one at a time, which is quite fast.  The size of the answers first grows and then shrinks, as shown at the end.

```
Eliminate[%, y12] // Simplify;
Eliminate[%, y22] // Simplify;
Eliminate[%, y11] // Simplify;
Eliminate[%, h1] // Simplify;
Eliminate[%, h2] // Simplify

(*
   c1^3 (c12^2 c23 - c13^2 c23 + c12 c13 (-c22 + c33)) + c12^3 c2^2 (c3 - h3) + 
   c1 (2 c13^2 c2^2 c23 - c2^2 c23^3 + c2 c22 c23^2 c3 + 
   c13^2 c23 c3^2 + c23^3 c3^2 + c2^2 c22 c23 c33 + 
   c13^2 c2 c3 c33 - c2 c22^2 c3 c33 - c2 c23^2 c3 c33 - 
   c22 c23 c3^2 c33 + c2 c22 c3 c33^2 + 
   c11^2 (c2^2 c23 - c2 (c22 - c33) (c3 - h3) - c23 (c3 - h3)^2) - 
   c12^2 (c2^2 c23 + c2 c22 (c3 - h3) + 2 c23 (c3 - h3)^2) + 
   c12 c13 (c2^2 (2 c22 - c33) + (c22 - 2 c33) (c3 - h3)^2) + 
   c11 (-c2^2 c23 (c22 + c33) + c12 c13 (-c2^2 + (c3 - h3)^2) + 
   c12^2 c2 (c3 - h3) - c2 (c13^2 - c22^2 + c33^2) (c3 - h3) + 
   c23 (c22 + c33) (c3 - h3)^2) - c2 c22 c23^2 h3 - 
   2 c13^2 c23 c3 h3 - 2 c23^3 c3 h3 - c13^2 c2 c33 h3 + 
   c2 c22^2 c33 h3 + c2 c23^2 c33 h3 + 2 c22 c23 c3 c33 h3 - 
   c2 c22 c33^2 h3 + c13^2 c23 h3^2 + c23^3 h3^2 - c22 c23 c33 h3^2) + 
   c12 (c11 c2 (c2^2 c23 - c2 (c22 - c33) (c3 - h3) - c23 (c3 - h3)^2) + 
   c13^2 (-2 c2^2 + (c3 - h3)^2) (c3 - h3) - (c2^2 c23 - 
   c2 (c22 - c33) (c3 - h3) - c23 (c3 - h3)^2) (c2 c33 + c23 (-c3 + h3))) + 
   c1^2 (c12^2 c13 c2 + c12 (c2 c23 (c22 + c33) + 
   c11 (-2 c2 c23 + (c22 - c33) (c3 - h3)) - (c13^2 - 
   2 c23^2 + (c22 - c33) c33) (c3 - h3)) + c12^3 (-c3 + h3) + 
   c13 (c13^2 c2 - c2 c22^2 - 2 c2 c23^2 - c22 c23 c3 + c2 c22 c33 -
   c23 c3 c33 + c22 c23 h3 + c23 c33 h3 + 
   c11 (c2 c22 + 2 c23 c3 - c2 c33 - 2 c23 h3))) == 
   c13 (-c2^3 c23^2 + c12^2 c2 (c2^2 - 2 (c3 - h3)^2) - 
   c2^2 c23 (c11 - 2 c22 + c33) (c3 - h3) + 
   c2 (c13^2 - c22^2 + c23^2 + c11 (c22 - c33) + c22 c33) (c3 - 
   h3)^2 + (c11 - c22) c23 (c3 - h3)^3)
*)
```

a cubic in `h3`, which can be solved with `Solve`, although the resulting expressions are enormous (a `LeafCount` of `154557`).  In principle one could back-substitute the `h3` solutions into the preceding equation and solve for `h2`, etc.  However, the subsequent expressions are likely to be equally enormous.  So, it is no wonder that a brute force solution using `Solve` on the original equations takes forever.  The sizes of the `Eliminate` intermediate answers as measured by `LeafCount`, including the first and last answers given above, are

[image]