# Solving Nonlinear System

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear

I am solving a $3X3$ non-linear system (posted also in [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671907/possible-application-of-the-implicit-function-theorem)).After some simplifying assumptions it looks like this:

$$K c_1 x_1=(1-x_2)(1-x_3)+a_1(1-x_2)x_3+a_2(1-x_3)x_2+a_3x_3x_2$$
$$K c_2 x_2=(1-x_1)(1-x_3)+a_5(1-x_1)x_3+a_6(1-x_3)x_1+a_7x_3x_1$$
$$K c_3x_3=(1-x_2)(1-x_1)+a_9(1-x_2)x_1+a_{10}(1-x_1)x_2+a_{11}x_1x_2$$

where $K, c_1,c_2,c_3>0$ and $x_1,x_2,x_3\in [0,1]$. I want to solve for $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Inspired in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86769/solve-a-system-of-non-linear-equations) I tried the following code:

```
Eliminate[
  x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + a1 (1 - x2) x3 + a2 (1 - x3) x2 + 
     a3 x2 x3 && 
   x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + a5 (1 - x1) x3 + a6 (1 - x3) x1 + 
     a7 x1 x3 && 
   x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + a9 (1 - x2) x1 + a10 (1 - x1) x2 + 
     a11 x2 x1, {x1}] // Simplify
```

but it's been running for a long time without any results. Do you suggest any other approaches? `Solve[]` also does not do the trick.

**EDIT**

After correcting a couple of typos one gets the output

```
c1 c2 x2 == 
  d (c1 + (-1 + a5) c1 x3 + 
     d (1 + a6 (-1 + x3) + (-1 + a5 - a7) x3) (-1 + x2 + 
        a2 x2 (-1 + x3) + x3 - a1 x3 + (-1 + a1 - a3) x2 x3)) && 
 c1 c3 x3 == 
  d (c1 + (-1 + a10) c1 x2 + 
     d (1 + a9 (-1 + x2) + (-1 + a10 - a11) x2) (-1 + x2 + 
        a2 x2 (-1 + x3) + x3 - a1 x3 + (-1 + a1 - a3) x2 x3)) && 
 c2 x2 + a11 d x2 + a10 c2 x2^2 + a6 d (1 + (-1 + a10) x2) (-1 + x3) +
    a11 a5 d x2 x3 + a7 d x2 x3 + 
   c3 x3 (-1 + a6 - a6 x3 + (1 - a5 + a7) x3) == (1 + a11) c2 x2^2 + 
   d (a7 + a11 x2 + a10 a7 x2) x3 + 
   a9 (-1 + x2) (d - c2 x2 + (-1 + a5) d x3) && d != 0
```

The problem is that then running `Eliminate[%, x2] // Simplify` also runs for a long time.

Comment: Your 3rd equation in text ends with `..x2+a11 x1 x2` Your 3rd equation in code ends with `..x1+a3 x2 x1` I assume `x2` or `x1` and `a11` or `a3` are typos. Since x1 only appears in simple form on the LHS of your 1st equation you could do `{1st,2nd}/.x1->((1-x2)(1-x3)+a1(1-x2)x3+a2(1-x3)x2+a3 x2 x3)d/c1//Simplify` to make this into two equations in two unknowns that are not much more complicated, but I don't know if that will help enough or not.

Comment: Oh thanks! There are indeed a couple of typos-let me check if that helps.

Comment: One can start with e.g. `With[{a1 = 1, a2 = 1, a3 = 1, a5 = 1, a6 = 1, a7 = 1, a9 = 1, a10 = 1, a11 = 1}, Reduce[{x1 c1 k == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + a1 (1 - x2) x3 + a2 (1 - x3) x2 + a3 x2 x3, 
   x2 c2 k == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + a5 (1 - x1) x3 + a6 (1 - x3) x1 + a7 x1 x3, x3 c3 k == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + a9 (1 - x2) x1 + a10 (1 - x1) x1 + a11 x2 x1, 0 <= x1 <= 1, 0 <= x2 <= 1, 0 <= x3 <= 1, k > 0, c1 > 0, c2 > 0, c3 > 0}, {x1, x2, x3}]]`.  Then you can consider eliminating assumptions on ak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm...(see bottom for caveat)

```
    In[19]:= Timing[res=Eliminate[
x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + a1 (1 - x2) x3 +
     a2 (1 - x3) x2 + a3 x2 x3 &&
x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) +
  a5 (1 - x1) x3 + a6 (1 - x3) x1 + a7 x1 x3 &&
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + a9
     (1 - x2) x1 + a10 (1 - x1) x2 + a11 x2 x1, {x1}];]

                   

(* Out[19]= {0.372933, Null} *)
```

It's pretty big though.

```
In[20]:= LeafCount[res]                                                         

(* Out[20]= 69503 *)
```

We can eliminate `x2` now.

```
In[27]:= Timing[res2 = Eliminate[res,{x2}];]                                    

(* Out[27]= {27.7586, Null} *)
```

Still big.

```
In[28]:= LeafCount[res2]                                                        

(* Out[28]= 14663 *)
```

Much faster to eliminate both in one go though.

```
Timing[res12=Eliminate[x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + a1 (1 - x2) x3
 + a2 (1 - x3) x2 + a3 x2 x3 && x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + a5 (1 -
 x1) x3 + a6 (1 - x3) x1 +  a7 x1 x3 &&     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + 
a9 (1 - x2) x1 + a10 (1 - x1) x2 + a11 x2 x1, {x1,x2}];] 

             

(* Out[30]= {0.761608, Null} *)

In[31]:= Length[res12]                                                          

(* Out[31]= 2 *)

In[32]:= LeafCount[res12]                                                       

(* Out[32]= 14663 *)
```

The catch is that this requires version 13.next. My way of saying I finally got around to speeding up `Eliminate` for the case of polynomial (or rational function) equations. To do this with the current version, one might change equations to expressions and use `GroebnerBasis`. I recommend an explicit term order option setting of `EliminationOrder`.

Comment: Very thoughtful! Thanks