# Best way to replace parameters with functions

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, evaluation

I recently solved [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283229/solving-nonlinear-system/283236#283236) Nonlinear system using `Eliminate`:

```
Eliminate[
  x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x2) x3 + m2 (1 - x3) x2 + 
     m3 x2 x3 && 
   x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x1) x3 + m6 (1 - x3) x1 + 
     m7 x1 x3 && 
   x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x2) x1 + m10 (1 - x1) x2 + 
     m11 x2 x1, {x1, x3}]]
```

It gives me a large expression that depends on parameters and `x2`. In practice, the coefficients $m_i$ are functions of some original parameters of my problem and I would like to evaluate the solution in my functional forms and plot it. For this, I have tried the following:

```
g1[a1_,b_]=Max[a1+b,0]
f[x2_] = With[{c1 = 1, c2 = 1, c3 = 1,m1=g1[a1,b]} , 
  Eliminate[
   x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x2) x3 + m2 (1 - x3) x2 + 
      m3 x2 x3 && 
    x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x1) x3 + m6 (1 - x3) x1 + 
      m7 x1 x3 && 
    x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x2) x1 + m10 (1 - x1) x2 + 
      m11 x2 x1, {x1, x3}]]
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x2], {x2, 0, 1}], {a1, 0, 1}, {m2, 0, 1}, {m3, 0, 1}, {m5, 0, 
  1}, {m6, 0, 1}, {m7, 0, 1}, {m9, 0, 1}, {m10, 0, 1},{m11, 0, 1},[b,0,1]]
```

In general, I have much more functions like `g1[a1_,b_]` that map into my coefficients, but this code already fails to work. Indeed, even omitting the function $g$ and instead leaving the code as `With[{c1 = 1, c2 = 1, c3 = 1}`  does not seem to work. Would you suggest a more efficient way of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

res = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x2) x3 + m2 (1 - x3) x2 + 
       m3 x2 x3 &&
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x1) x3 + m6 (1 - x3) x1 + 
       m7 x1 x3 &&
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x2) x1 + m10 (1 - x1) x2 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x1, x3}] //
   Simplify;

LeafCount@res

(* 620 *)

g1[a1_, b_] = Max[a1 + b, 0];
```

Using [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 dv = Max[dv, 0.01];
 {m2, m3, m5, m6, m7, m9, m10, m11, a1, b, d} =
  Rationalize[
   {m2v, m3v, m5v, m6v, m7v, m9v, m10v, m11v, a1v, bv, dv}];
 c1 = 1; c2 = 1; c3 = 1; m1 = g1[a1, b];
 f[x2_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res // Simplify));
 Plot[Tooltip@f[x], {x, 0, 1},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
     {HoldForm[x2], HoldForm[f]})],
 Evaluate[
  Grid[
   Map[Control,
    Partition[
     ({{#, 0.5, StringDrop[ToString[#], -1]}, 0, 1, 0.01,
         Appearance -> "Labeled",
         ImageSize -> Small} & /@
       {m2v, m3v, m5v, m6v, m7v, m9v, m10v, m11v, a1v, bv, dv}),
     UpTo[2]],
    {2}]]],
 ControlPlacement -> Top,
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :>
  {m2v, m3v, m5v, m6v, m7v, m9v, m10v, m11v, a1v, bv, dv}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob! May I ask what exactly are we plotting here? Naturally I would be looking for the value of $x_2$ that solves the expression in 'res' as a function of my parameters. But such expression is quite NonLinear...So may I ask about what object are we looking at? (Sorry, newbie here)

Comment: Your code implied that you wanted to plot a function of `x2`. Values are substituted in `res` for all variables except `x2`. This leaves an equation such as `84 + 3 x2^2 + x2^3 == 244 x2` What is plotted is LHS-RHS of this equation, i.e., the roots of this equation are the zero crossings. Due to the restricted range of the plot, not all roots are shown.

Comment: That's what I thought, yes. It is ok to restrict to only those roots cause I am working in $[0,1]$. Is there a quick way to retrieve such roots (i.e: crossings) and save them as a function of parameters?

Comment: In the `Manipulate`, add `root = SolveValues[{f[x2] == 0, 0 <= x2 <= 1}, x2, Reals][[1]];` and then `Append` the parameters and roots into a list of the solutions.