# Find solutions after using Eliminate

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, evaluation

I have used `Eliminate[]` to reduce a system of equations as found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283229/solving-nonlinear-system/283236#283236), I then proceeded to verify that indeed my system has zeros using [this code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283253/71975). My question is, what is the best way to retrieve those zeros for $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ as a function of my parameters?

For replication, this is my code:

```
res2 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x1, x3}] // Simplify;
LeafCount@res2
res1 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x2, x3}] // Simplify;
LeafCount@res1
res3 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x1, x2}] // Simplify;
LeafCount@res3
X12[a1_, a2_, b_] = Min[Max[0.5 + b (a1 - a2), 0], 1];
X13[a1_, a3_, b_] = Min[Max[0.5 + b (a1 - a3), 0], 1];
X23[a2_, a3_, b_] = Min[Max[0.5 + b (a2 - a3), 0], 1];
X123[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p2_, p3_] = 
  Min[Max[0.5 + 0.5*b*(2 a1 - a2 - a3) - 0.5 (p3 - p2), 0], 1];
X213[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, p3_] = 
  Min[Max[0.5 + 0.5*b*(2 a2 - a2 - a1) - 0.5 (p2 - p1), 0], 1];
g1[a1_, a2_, b_] = X12[a1, a2, b]/(1 + a1);
g2[a1_, a3_, b_] = X13[a1, a3, b]/(1 + a1);
g3[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p2_, 
   p3_] = (X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3]/(1 + a1));
g5[a1_, a2_, b_] = (X12[a1, a2, b])/(1 + a2);
g6[a2_, a3_, b_] = X23[a2, a3, b]/(1 + a2);
g7[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3]/(1 + a2));
g9[a2_, a3_, b_] = (1 - X23[a2, a3, b])/(1 + a3);
g10[a1_, a3_, b_] = (X13[a1, a3, b])/(1 + a3);
g11[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (1 - (X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3] - 
       X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3])/(1 + a3));
```

And I can plot these solutions using:

```
Manipulate[dv = Max[dv, 0.01];
 {a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p2, p3, d} = 
  Rationalize[{a1v, a2v, a3v, bv, p1v, p2v, p3v, dv}];
 c1 = 1; c2 = 1; c3 = 1; m1 = g1[a1, a2, b]; m2 = g2[a1, a3, b]; 
 m3 = g3[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3];
 m5 = g5[a1, a2, b];
 m6 = g6[a2, a3, b];
 m7 = g7[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3];
 m9 = g9[a2, a3, b];
 m10 = g9[a2, a3, b];
 m11 = g11[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3];
 f1[x1_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res1 // Simplify));
 f2[x2_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res2 // Simplify));
 f3[x3_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res3 // Simplify));
 Plot[{Tooltip@f1[x], Tooltip@f2[x], Tooltip@f3[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 8] & /@ {HoldForm[x2], HoldForm[f]})], 
 Evaluate[Grid[
   Map[Control, 
    Partition[({{#, 0.5, StringDrop[ToString[#], -1]}, 0, 1, 0.01, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small} & /@ {a1v, a2v, 
        a3v, bv, p1v, p2v, p3v, dv}), UpTo[2]], {2}]]], 
 ControlPlacement -> Top, SynchronousUpdating -> False, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {a1v, a2v, a3v, bv, p1v, p2v, p3v, dv}]
```

Which gives me:
[image]

It clearly shows that $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ do have solutions. How would you suggest I retrieve them?

Comment: This is very complicated. Among other things, there is a subtraction of polynomials that seems like an unusual thing to do. In words, what problem involving the original polynomials are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I am solving a 3x3 system as in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671907/possible-application-of-the-implicit-function-theorem

Comment: The link has a question I can follow, at least in the case where the `f(x)` are explicit polynomial (perhaps linear) functions of `x`. What I do not follow is how it is related to the functions in the manipulation shown in this post. If you solve for the set `{x1,x2,x3}`, assuming all parameters have numeric values, you should get a set of points in C^3 (five such, to be specific). Is it the zero-crossings you are looking for? If so, there's an easier way to go about this.

Comment: To be clear, this is what I intend to do: (i) get Mathematica to solve the system in the link above; (ii) obtain expressions for $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in terms of my parameters ($m_i$) (iii) evaluate $m_i$ in the actual parameters of my problem (which are defined trough the $g_i$ functions inside the Manipulate). I think step (iii) is what bothers you? Would you suggest another approach?/

Comment: Easier to do step (iii) first (guess that would make it step (i)), then call NSolve on the “instantiated” numeric system.

Comment: My only concern is that I would "prioritize" algebraic solutions-and Solve does take a long time with this system.

Comment: The algebraic solution involves parametrized Root objects of degree 5, and is quite possibly too big to be of practical use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = Join[Thread[
    0 <= {a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p2, p3, x1, x2, x3} <= 1], {0 < d <= 1}];

c1 = 1; c2 = 1; c3 = 1;

res2 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x1, x3}] // Simplify;
res1 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x2, x3}] // Simplify;
res3 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x1, x2}] // Simplify;
X12[a1_, a2_, b_] = Min[Max[1/2 + b (a1 - a2), 0], 1];
X13[a1_, a3_, b_] = Min[Max[1/2 + b (a1 - a3), 0], 1];
X23[a2_, a3_, b_] = Min[Max[1/2 + b (a2 - a3), 0], 1];
X123[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p2_, p3_] = 
  Min[Max[1/2 + 1/2*b*(2 a1 - a2 - a3) - 1/2 (p3 - p2), 0], 1];
X213[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, p3_] = 
  Min[Max[1/2 + 1/2*b*(2 a2 - a2 - a1) - 1/2 (p2 - p1), 0], 1];
g1[a1_, a2_, b_] = X12[a1, a2, b]/(1 + a1);
g2[a1_, a3_, b_] = X13[a1, a3, b]/(1 + a1);
g3[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p2_, 
   p3_] = (X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3]/(1 + a1));
g5[a1_, a2_, b_] = (X12[a1, a2, b])/(1 + a2);
g6[a2_, a3_, b_] = X23[a2, a3, b]/(1 + a2);
g7[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3]/(1 + a2));
g9[a2_, a3_, b_] = (1 - X23[a2, a3, b])/(1 + a3);
g10[a1_, a3_, b_] = (X13[a1, a3, b])/(1 + a3);
g11[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (1 - (X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3] - 
       X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3])/(1 + a3));

header = {"roots", "a1", "a2", "a3", "b", "p1", "p2", "p3", "d"};

solutions = {header};
```

Add determination of roots to [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[dv = Max[dv, 0.01];
 {a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p2, p3, d} = Rationalize[
   {a1v, a2v, a3v, bv, p1v, p2v, p3v, dv}];
 m1 = g1[a1, a2, b]; m2 = g2[a1, a3, b];
 m3 = g3[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3];
 m5 = g5[a1, a2, b]; m6 = g6[a2, a3, b];
 m7 = g7[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3];
 m9 = g9[a2, a3, b]; m10 = g9[a2, a3, b];
 m11 = g11[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3];
 f1[x1_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res1 // Simplify));
 root1 = Solve[{f1[x1] == 0, 0 <= x1 <= 1}, x1][[1]];
 f2[x2_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res2 // Simplify));
 root2 = Solve[{f2[x2] == 0, 0 <= x2 <= 1}, x2][[1]];
 f3[x3_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res3 // Simplify));
 root3 = Solve[{f3[x3] == 0, 0 <= x3 <= 1}, x3][[1]];
 roots = Flatten@N@{root1, root2, root3};
 solutions = Append[solutions,
   N@{roots, a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p2, p3, d}];
 Column[{roots,
   Plot[{Tooltip@f1[x], Tooltip@f2[x], Tooltip@f3[x]}, {x, 0, 1},
    PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 8] & /@ {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[f]}),
    ImageSize -> Medium]}],
 Evaluate[Grid[Map[Control,
    Partition[(
      {{#, 0.5, StringDrop[ToString[#], -1]}, 0, 1, 0.01,
         Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small} & /@
       {a1v, a2v, a3v, bv, p1v, p2v, p3v, dv}),
     UpTo[2]], {2}]]],
 ControlPlacement -> Top,
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {a1v, a2v, a3v, bv, p1v, p2v, p3v, dv}]
```

[image]

After some manipulation of the controls

```
solutions // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob, that works smoothly. As I understand with this method then root1, root2, and root3 have my three solutions. However, when I call them they are already evaluated. Would it be possible to retrieve them as a function of my  parameters?

Comment: Yes, but why then did you ask this in terms of a Manipulate. Just write a Solve of three equations for three unknowns.

Comment: The problem is that if I just do that then Solve takes forever, Eliminate helps me reduce this to simpler expressions.