# Optimizing my code to solve nonlinear system

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, evaluation, nonlinear

I have solved a non-linear system using `Eliminate[]` and `Solve[]`, using a really nice answer [found here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283312/71975) I am able to use `Manipulate[]` to have an idea of how my solution varies according to my parameters of interest.

I now want to obtain an algebraic solution (or an approximation) that I can report. I thought that this would be possible using the following code, which is essentially adapting what Bob Hanlon does inside the `Manipulate[]`. The first chunk is the preamble, which uses `Eliminate[]` and establishes my parameters:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = 
  Join[Thread[
    0 <= {a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p2, p3, x1, x2, x3} <= 1], {0 < d <= 1}];

c1 = 1; c2 = 1; c3 = 1;

res2 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x1, x3}] // Simplify;
res1 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x2, x3}] // Simplify;
res3 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x1, x2}] // Simplify;
X12[a1_, a2_, b_] = Min[Max[1/2 + b (a1 - a2), 0], 1];
X13[a1_, a3_, b_] = Min[Max[1/2 + b (a1 - a3), 0], 1];
X23[a2_, a3_, b_] = Min[Max[1/2 + b (a2 - a3), 0], 1];
X123[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p2_, p3_] = 
  Min[Max[1/2 + 1/2*b*(2 a1 - a2 - a3) - 1/2 (p3 - p2), 0], 1];
X213[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, p3_] = 
  Min[Max[1/2*b*(2 a2 - a2 - a1) + 1/2 (p3 - p1), 0], 1];
g1[a1_, a2_, b_] = X12[a1, a2, b]/(1 + a1);
g2[a1_, a3_, b_] = X13[a1, a3, b]/(1 + a1);
g3[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p2_, 
   p3_] = (X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3]/(1 + a1));
g5[a1_, a2_, b_] = (X12[a1, a2, b])/(1 + a2);
g6[a2_, a3_, b_] = X23[a2, a3, b]/(1 + a2);
g7[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3]/(1 + a2));
g9[a2_, a3_, b_] = (1 - X23[a2, a3, b])/(1 + a3);
g10[a1_, a3_, b_] = (X13[a1, a3, b])/(1 + a3);
g11[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (1 - (X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3] + 
       X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3])/(1 + a3));

header = {"roots", "a1", "a2", "a3", "b", "p1", "p2", "p3", "d"};

solutions = {header};
```

And then I run  this second chunk that uses `Solve[]` to retrieve my roots in $[0,1]$:

```
m1 = g1[a1, a2, b]; m2 = g2[a1, a3, b];
m3 = g3[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3];
m5 = g5[a1, a2, b]; m6 = g6[a2, a3, b];
m7 = g7[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3];
m9 = g9[a2, a3, b]; m10 = g9[a2, a3, b];
m11 = g11[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3];
f1[x1_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res1 // Simplify));
root1 = Solve[{f1[x1] == 0, 0 <= x1 <= 1}, x1][[1]];
```

However, this takes a long time and I get this error message:

```
Simplify::time: Time spent on a transformation exceeded 300.` seconds, and the transformation was aborted. Increasing the value of TimeConstraint option may improve the result of simplification.
```

I am still learning about optimization using Mathematica and would like to be clear that my goal is to get a close algebraic approximation of my solutions in the interval of interest. So if there is a trade-off between using `Eliminate[]` first and then `Solve[]` I would be happy to listen to your opinion. Perhaps a better approach is just to directly use `Nsolve[]`?