# Computing determinant inside Manipulate

Tags: mathematical-optimization, manipulate, nonlinear

I am solving a Nonlinear system, using the solution proposed by Bob [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283312/71975). I am interested in computing a reporting the determinant of the Jacobian of my system.

For this, I compute the derivatives manually and then use `Det` to compute the value of the determinant. For some cases, Mathematica does solve it rather fast, for instance, setting:

```
p1 = 1/3; p2 = 2/3; p3 = 1; a1 = 0; a2 = 0; a3 = 0; b = 0;
```

However, once `b>0` the computations naturally become very demanding.

I was wondering if you have suggestions to compute this determinant. I think it should be possible to compute it inside the Manipulate using the roots, but so far have not succeeded.

This is my code:

```
Assumptions
Clear["Global`*"]
$Assumptions = 
  Join[Thread[
    0 <= {a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p2, p3, x1, x2, x3} <= 1], {0 < d <= 1}];
p1 = 1/3; p2 = 2/3; p3 = 1;

System:
res2 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x1, x3}] // Simplify;
res1 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x2, x3}] // Simplify;
res3 = Eliminate[
    x1*c1/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x3) + m1 (1 - x3) x2 + m2 (1 - x2) x3 + 
       m3 x2 x3 && 
     x2*c2/d == (1 - x1) (1 - x3) + m5 (1 - x3) x1 + m6 (1 - x1) x3 + 
       m7 x1 x3 && 
     x3*c3/d == (1 - x2) (1 - x1) + m9 (1 - x1) x2 + m10 (1 - x2) x1 +
        m11 x2 x1, {x1, x2}] // Simplify;
X12[a1_, a2_, b_] = Min[Max[1/2 + b (a1 - a2), 0], 1];
X13[a1_, a3_, b_] = Min[Max[1/2 + b (a1 - a3), 0], 1];
X23[a2_, a3_, b_] = Min[Max[1/2 + b (a2 - a3), 0], 1];
X123[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p2_, p3_] = 
  Min[Max[1/2 + 1/2*b*(2 a1 - a2 - a3) - 1/2 (p3 - p2), 0], 1];
X213[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, p3_] = 
  Min[Max[1/2*b*(2 a2 - a3 - a1) + 1/2 (p3 - p1), 0], 1];
g1[a1_, a2_, b_] = X12[a1, a2, b]/(1 + a1);
g2[a1_, a3_, b_] = X13[a1, a3, b]/(1 + a1);
g3[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p2_, 
   p3_] = (X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3]/(1 + a1));
g5[a1_, a2_, b_] = (1 - X12[a1, a2, b])/(1 + a2);
g6[a2_, a3_, b_] = X23[a2, a3, b]/(1 + a2);
g7[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3]/(1 + a2));
g9[a2_, a3_, b_] = (1 - X23[a2, a3, b])/(1 + a3);
g10[a1_, a3_, b_] = (X13[a1, a3, b])/(1 + a3);
g11[a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (1 - (X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3] + 
       X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3]))/(1 + a3);
```

Objects for the jacobian:

```
F11[c1_, d_] = c1/d;
F12[x3_, a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (1 + ((X12[a1, a2, b])/(1 + 
         a1))) - (x3*(((X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3] + (1/3))/(1 + 
           a1)) + 1));
F13[x2_, a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (1 + ((X13[a1, a3, b])/(1 + 
         a1))) - (x2*(((X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3] + (1/3))/(1 + 
           a1)) + 1));
F21[x3_, a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (1 + ((1 - X12[a1, a2, b])/(1 + 
         a2))) - (x3*(((X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3] + (1/3))/(1 + 
           a2)) + 1));
F22[c2_, d_] = c2/d;
F23[x1_, a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (1 + ((X23[a2, a3, b])/(1 + 
         a2))) - (x1*(((X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3] + (1/3))/(1 + 
           a2)) + 1));
F31[x2_, a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (1 + ((1 - X13[a1, a3, b])/(1 + 
         a3))) - (x2*(((1 - (X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3] + 
             X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3]) + (1/3))/(1 + a3)) + 1));
F32[x1_, a1_, a2_, a3_, b_, p1_, 
   p3_] = (1 + ((1 - X23[a2, a3, b])/(1 + 
         a3))) - (x1*(((1 - (X213[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3] + 
             X123[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3]) + (1/3))/(1 + a3)) + 1));
F33[c3_, d_] = c3/d;
```

And the determinant is:

```
Det[{{F11[c1, d], F12[x3, a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3], 
   F13[x2, a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3]}, {F21[x3, a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3], 
   F22[c2, d], 
   F23[x1, a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3]}, {F31[x2, a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3], 
   F32[x1, a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3], F33[c3, d]}}]
```

Manipulate:

```
header = {"roots", "a1", "a2", "a3", "b", "d"};

solutions = {header}; Manipulate[dv = Max[dv, 0.01];
 {a1, a2, a3, b, d} = Rationalize[{a1v, a2v, a3v, bv, dv}];
 m1 = g1[a1, a2, b]; m2 = g2[a1, a3, b];
 m3 = g3[a1, a2, a3, b, p2, p3];
 m5 = g5[a1, a2, b]; m6 = g6[a2, a3, b];
 m7 = g7[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3];
 m9 = g9[a2, a3, b]; m10 = g9[a2, a3, b];
 m11 = g11[a1, a2, a3, b, p1, p3];
 f1[x1_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res1 // Simplify));
 root1 = Solve[{f1[x1] == 0, 0 <= x1 <= 1}, x1][[1]];
 f2[x2_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res2 // Simplify));
 root2 = Solve[{f2[x2] == 0, 0 <= x2 <= 1}, x2][[1]];
 f3[x3_] = (#[[1]] - #[[-1]] &@(res3 // Simplify));
 root3 = Solve[{f3[x3] == 0, 0 <= x3 <= 1}, x3][[1]];
 roots = Flatten@N@{root1, root2, root3};
 solutions = Append[solutions, N@{roots, a1, a2, a3, b, d}];
 Column[{roots, 
   Plot[{Tooltip@f1[x], Tooltip@f2[x], Tooltip@f3[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 5] & /@ {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[f]}), 
    ImageSize -> Medium]}], 
 Evaluate[Grid[
   Map[Control, 
    Partition[({{#, 0.1, StringDrop[ToString[#], -1]}, 0, 1, 0.01, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small} & /@ {a1v, a2v, 
        a3v, bv, dv}), UpTo[2]], {2}]]], ControlPlacement -> Top, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {a1v, a2v, a3v, bv, dv}] 

solutions // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```